# Is it wise to "exploit" java call-by-value

Tags: java, methods, pass-by-reference

Consider the following siutation. A user can enter something like
30D, 90D, 180D, 360D, 1M, 3M, 6M, 12M, 1Y
(D=day, M=month, Y=year).

I want to compute the number of months with the following two methods.

```
    private int getLengthOfPeriodInMonths(Integer lengthOfPeriod, String unitOfPeriod) {
        int periodInMonths = lengthOfPeriod;
        if ("D".equals(unitOfPeriod)) {
            periodInMonths = lengthOfPeriod / 30;
        } else if ("Y".equals(unitOfPeriod)) {
            periodInMonths = lengthOfPeriod * 12;
        }
        return periodInMonths;
    }

    private int getLengthOfPeriodInMonths(Integer lengthOfPeriod, String unitOfPeriod) {
        if ("D".equals(unitOfPeriod)) {
            lengthOfPeriod = lengthOfPeriod / 30;
        } else if ("Y".equals(unitOfPeriod)) {
            lengthOfPeriod = lengthOfPeriod * 12;
        }
        return lengthOfPeriod;
    }
```

Because java works with call-by-value with a reference passed as a value `lengthOfPeriod` won't change outside of the method. I am not sure what is more appropriate to use.

I know that this method could be refactored by using an enum `Periods` or something like that. But let's not discuss this here.

Comment: could you explain what is supposed to happen here?

Comment: Do whichever makes your code clearer. To me, they're both fine.

Comment: I think there might be one general problem: A programmer might change lengthOfPeriod (by setter) in the second method, which might change the code outside of this method.

Comment: Use neither of these and directly return your values: `return lengthOfPeriod / 30` in `if`, `return lengthOfPeriod * 12` in `else` and `return lengthOfPeriod;` outside the block.

Comment: @Tom I think it's almost always clearer to reduce the number of return statements in one method. There is the clause: "A method should always have one exit point".

Comment: And this clause is nonsense (imho) or at least a matter of own experiences/style. There is no problem with having more than one exit point, especially if one prefers "fail fast". Btw you can search either here or on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ for some discussions about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assigning to method parameters is not a good idea (and they should've been made final by default IMHO). If you really want to avoid the extra variable (not that it really makes a difference), you can put returns in your if clauses.

But don't use parameters as "automatic local variables". It can cause hard to see bugs and doesn't make your code any more performant.

Comment: I like this answer. Could you provide an example in which it will produce a bug? Do you mean the case when using setter-calls on the passed reference?

Comment: @Chris311 *"Could you provide an example in which it will produce a bug?"* for example `public void setBlub(String blub) { blub = blub;}` where the programmer assigns the parameter to itself, instead of using the field. Or when the programmer thinks, that reassigning the parameter will reflect to the calling method like: `String blub; setBlub(blub); .... public void setBlub(String blub) { blub = "default"; }`. By making the parameter `final` you'll avoid this problem.

Comment: @Chris311 Well, not specifically, but of course that's a potential problem too. Most methods *don't* assign to the parameters, so it's easier to overlook if you're making changes to a method. It's more consistent when you have the parameters as they originally were, and local variables if the parameters need to be preprocessed in some way.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is that you use an own variable `int periodInMonths = lengthOfPeriod;` in the first method. But this isn't necessary!

You can use the second one.. It does what it should!

```
int lengthOfPeriodInMonths = getLengthOfPeriodInMonths(lengthOfPeriod, unitOfPeriod);
```

and you have the calculated int outside of the method stored in `lengthOfPeriodInMonths`

P.S.: This call

```
lengthOfPeriod = lengthOfPeriod / 30;
```

is equivalent to

```
lengthOfPeriod = new Integer(lengthOfPeriod / 30);
```

(look "auto-boxing" in Java).

So, as you said, Java uses call-bay-value. The variable `lengthOfPeriod` gets assigned a new refernece in this call. So this calculation would be lost outside the method! That's why you must return the newly computed value!

Comment: That is exactly what I already know, but is it wise to forgo the use of a local variable?

Comment: Yes, because the execution of your program is a litttle little little bit quicker and it spares your working memory etc. ;) AND: Why to add something that isn't needed?!

Comment: @mrbela It has no effect on performance. It's what's known as *micro-optimization*, where you concentrate on things that really don't matter, but possibly write bad code instead. Code clarity far outweighs "saving" a local variable. It's better to concentrate on the things that actually matter than thinking "should I use 1 variable or 2".

Answer (score 0):

First advice: never ever modify the method parameters. They should reflect the value passed by the user of the method at all times.

Second advice: if someone advises you to never do something, especially if he or she uses the phrase "never ever", take his or her advice with a grain of salt. There are no rules without exceptions (never ever ;-). Such rules are great rules of thumb, but always use your own judgement. Choose the solution which you think is clearer. I know of some situations where I found modifying method parameters was more readable than the alternative.

For example, sometimes you might want to allow the user of the method to pass `null` to the method, but then replace it with some default value. I find the following method

```
public void doSomething(String s) {
    if (s == null) s = "";
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

much clearer than introducing a local variable just to include the default value:

```
public void doSomething(final String s) {
    String sOrEmpty = s == null ? "" : s;
    System.out.println(sOrEmpty);
}
```